# Powershell invoking remote script to get farmload (XenApp 4.5)

Tags: powershell, remoting, citrix, invoke-command, xenapp

qfarm /loadI have a problem with remote executing a script.

The script invokes a command for cmd `qfarm /load` and converts the result to PSObjects.

```
function New-qLast()
{
    param ([String] $qName, [String] $qLoad)
    $qLast = New-Object PSObject

    $qLast | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $qName
    $qLast | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerLast -Value $qLoad

    return $qLast
}

Write-Host "Start" 

$b = @()
foreach ($a in $(qfarm /load))
{
    $b += $a.Split(" ") | Where-Object { $_ -ne "" }
}
$b

$table = @()
for ($i = 5; $i -lt $b.Length; $i += 2) #for XA 4.5 $i = 5 $i += 2; for XA 6.5 $i += 5 and $i = 8
{
    $table += New-qLast $b[$i] $b[$i+1]
}
$table
```

as soon as it get's to invoking the `qfarm /load` nothing is happening anymore.

When I execute the script directly on a terminal server it works fine.

I also tried to run `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 {qfarm /load}` that works for the first 22 servers of the farm then it's not returning anything but still running till you manually turn it off.

Has anyone an idea why it get's stuck?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `qfarm /load` what is it, and what does it do?

Comment: It looks like `qfarm /load` returns servername and load, is that right? `qfarm` is a command that was made for CMD so it will return text not an object. So, `$(qfarm /load)` may not work. Do `$test = (qfarm /load); $test.gettype()`. My guess is the it will be an array of strings.

Comment: Try `$data = cmd /c 'qfarm /load'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks Bob and sorry for my late reply.

Unfortunately your method doesn't work, but I found a way around.

I found this [VBS](http://www.cibengineering.com/blog/server-load-level-wmi/) and used it for my PowerShellscript.

It looks like this:

```
$server = Import-Csv C:\Server_On.txt | Where-Object { $_.ServerStatus -eq $true }

$load = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server.ServerName -Namespace "root\citrix" -Class MetaFrame_Server_LoadLevel | Select-Object Servername, LoadLevel
```

the only difference to `qfarm /load` is that you have to address every single server.